# Having issue with rotation of cube in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

[image]

I am trying to rotate cube which is placed far away from origin(0,0), like i set model view projection using `glOrtho( 80, 81, 25, 26, -100, 100);` 
When i rotate object it will look like stretched its not seem properly, i also tried the method translation , rotation and again translate back to original position but its not work its just displaced the object.

Check in figure A. before rotating and after roatating it will be stretched like figure B.
Any body faced this type of problem

Comment: What is the purpose of your `glOrtho` call? This method is supposed to create a projection matrix. The values you provide seem a little weird. Do the preserve the viewport's aspect ratio? How do you place the cube? By specifying according vertex positions or by defining a translation matrix? Please add your rotation code (both versions).

Comment: glOrtho does modifies the projection matrix. To rotate the cube, what you need to is change the modelview matrix which is done using. Are you calling glOrtho between rotations?